# Proper image orientation in AngularJS 1.5 project

Tags: css, angularjs, image, orientation

Landscape images taken from iPhone appear upside down on Desktop Chrome, but proper orientation on iPhone Safari. An example is the car on the homepage https://www.dapidi.com/#/

I doubt the problem is with the browsers or devices. After searching for an answer I came across this directive which seems to work most times, but not for the image of this car. I believe this should be a "solved problem" already, but I cannot seem to find an answer. Anyone have a solution how to solve this surely common dilemma?

**DIRECTIVE**

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('imgOrientation', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element/*, attrs*/) {
                function setTransform(transform) {
                    element.css('-ms-transform', transform);
                    element.css('-webkit-transform', transform);
                    element.css('-moz-transform', transform);
                    element.css('transform', transform);
                }

                var parent = element.parent();
                $(element).bind('load', function() {
                    EXIF.getData(element[0], function() {
                        var orientation = EXIF.getTag(element[0], 'Orientation');
                        var height = element.height();
                        var width = element.width();
                        if (orientation && orientation !== 1) {
                            switch (orientation) {
                                case 2:
                                    setTransform('rotateY(180deg)');
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    setTransform('rotate(180deg)');
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    setTransform('rotateX(180deg)');
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    setTransform('rotateZ(90deg) rotateX(180deg)');
                                    if (width > height) {
                                        parent.css('height', width + 'px');
                                        element.css('margin-top', ((width -height) / 2) + 'px');
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    setTransform('rotate(90deg)');
                                    if (width > height) {
                                        parent.css('height', width + 'px');
                                        element.css('margin-top', ((width -height) / 2) + 'px');
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    setTransform('rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(180deg)');
                                    if (width > height) {
                                        parent.css('height', width + 'px');
                                        element.css('margin-top', ((width -height) / 2) + 'px');
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 8:
                                    setTransform('rotate(-90deg)');
                                    if (width > height) {
                                        parent.css('height', width + 'px');
                                        element.css('margin-top', ((width -height) / 2) + 'px');
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error. I had a typo in the directive attribute name in the HTML.
Was: img-fix-orientation
Should have been: img-orientation
(face palm)

Forgot I had renamed it at some point. 
The directive seems to work.